# How secure is your data in Android when an app is given access to storage, camera, contacts

Tags: applications, security, permissions, privacy, background-data

I am just trying to understand that, these days most of the apps require access to things like camera, storage, contacts.

Is there any data privacy link to read through for an app consumer to know what is all that an app is doing in your background, in simple English so that a non-tech person can also understand the effects

I see some apps, like a fitness apps, asking for camera access, and allow access to make calls, cannot join the dots like why does it require camera access and asking for permission to make calls. I'm sure there must be scan/check when an app is uploaded to Playstore, but is this point checked like why a fitness app is asking permission to make calls or camera access.

I am sure given an app, the app devs know exactly what all does the app does with all access permission in hand. Isn't it creepy sometimes from a consumer point of view.

A little I know is some apps collect our data and just sell it

Any online document link on privacy policy, data collection given an app, could help understand in detail. Could anyone throw some light or thoughts on app consumers data security in Android

Comment: Asking for on line resources and references is off topic here. Besides, the question looks pretty broad. //Consider editing by not asking for references, and narrowing the scope to the Android version you are using.  Examples of some specific apps, you have in mind may also be  additional  inputs

Comment: [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/231350/131553) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218485/131553) may help

Comment: Also see the [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/permissions/info) of permissions and the linked questions

Comment: [Are multiple-users protected from each other differently than apps?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213921/218526)